# Dealing with a change to the type of an existing field?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, lucene

If I had a simple object indexed in ES

```
{ "name" : "Mark", "age" : 30}
```

and then another object was added to the same index

```
{ "name" : "Bill", "age" : "forty"}
```

The mapping would fail to update, the new object would not get indexed. According to the elasticsearch docs

> "once a field has been added, its type can not change. For example, if we added age and its value is a number, then it can’t be treated as a string."

Is there any way around this to allow these similar `people` objects to exist (and be searchable) under the same index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't do that. Because once you declared the type of your field, you can't change it without re-indexing your whole data set again. (and of course, refactoring your code).

This is true for Apache Solr also.

One option could be introducing a new field (age_in_string) and populate it also with the values you want: "30" and "forty". You can search on that.

Comment: I was only using the `age` field to get my idea in cross. What I actually had in mind was allowing any number of fields to change, and in light of your explanation this clearly isn't possible. 
If I were to go the other route and reindex all the data then the previously indexed docs where `age` was a number would be ignored in favour of the new docs with `age` as a string, am I right in thinking that?